# Date driven table partitioning on date column from another table

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, database-trigger

I have trigger function that automatically creates child tables based on date column from parent table (table 1). Hovewer I have to make modification to do that based on date column from another table (table 2)!

Is this possible at all? I have foreign key in table 1 which is linked with a id column in table 2.

I searched over the internet but mostly found different scripts for task I already solved (date column in parent table, not in another table).

EXAMPLE: Make monthly partitions of table **invoice_details** based on invoice_date in table **invoice** (foreign key invoice_details.invoice_id - > invoice.invoice_id)

```
CREATE TABLE public.invoice_details
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    invoice_id integer NOT NULL,
    charge_type integer,
    charge_amount numeric(15,5),
    charge_tax numeric(15,5),
    charge_status character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE public.invoice
(
    invoice_id integer NOT NULL,
    customer character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    invoice_date date NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your schema and the intended partitioning?

Comment: I have edited question with additional code. Just a basic example with few columns.

Comment: Can there be many invoice_details for a single invoice?

Comment: Yes. One invoice will have many rows in details table.

Comment: I am starting to believe it is not possible. Problem can be taken down to a question: could SQL expression be used in CHECK statement e.g. "CREATE invoice_details_partition01 CHECK (invoice.invoice_date > date1 AND date2<=invoice.invoice_date)"

Comment: Would partitioning by invoice_id give you a similar effect? Or charge_type or charge_status? What's the motivation behind partitioning?

Comment: One invoice can have thousands of detail rows, and with thousand of invoices every month that could lead to slow peroformances. My client ask me to do partitioning of invoice_details by date of invoice. It has sense, but not with this table design. Maybe, if I have invoice_date in invoice_details too then I could check by date. In this way, I guess that only logical solutions is to do it by invoice_id. In that case I should estimate what range of ids would produce any effect, if any.

Comment: You'll want to avoid redundant data like copying `invoice_date` into `invoice_details`, but you could mitigate it with triggers. However, partitioning isn't about making big tables smaller, but making indexing and filtering easier. Partitioning `invoice_details` by `invoices.invoice_date` won't help because filtering by `invoice_date` is done in `invoices` and then it's a simple join. Other than `invoice_id`, which is easy to index, what fields will you most often filter by? For example, if you're often looking for invoices with outstanding balances, `charge_status` would be a good choice.

Comment: I undestand your point, and increase of performances was the main aim for this modification. I created one column in invoice_details with the date of invoice, for testing purposes. With 10 million of rows it is 4x faster with partitions (when filtering by date) since Postgresql uses index scan over that column. Without partitioning it uses sequential scan.

Comment: That's odd that it would do a sequential scan for a simple join. What query are you running? Is `invoice_details.invoice_id` declared as a foreign key and indexed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215149/discussion-between-darkvark-and-schwern).